# ! Argument of \begin has an extra }

Tags: tables

I have this error in Wiley book template

> ! Argument of \begin has an extra }.  
>                   \par  l.221 \begin{tabular}
>                        {cccccc} ?  Process interrupted by user

```
\begin{table}[bh!]
\centering
\caption{Properties of benchmark matrices}
%\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc} 
%\rowcolor{gray!50}
 \hline
 matrix          & rank & nonzero  & type & diagonally& Condition  \\
                   &        & elements &       & dominant & Number     \\ \hline
PLAT1919    & 1919 & 32399  & Symmetric Indefinite & No & 1.0e+02\\ 
PLAT362           & 362   & 5786    & Symmetric Indefinite & No & 7.1e+11\\
GR 30 30    & 900   & 7744  & Symmetric Positive-definite & Weakly & 3.8e+02\\
BCSSTK22    & 138   & 696       & Symmetric Indefinite & No & 1.7e+05\\
NOS4        & 100   & 594       & Symmetric Positive-definite & No & 2.7e+03\\ 
HOR 131     & 434   & 4710  & Asymmetric & No & 1.3e+05\\ 
NOS6        & 675   & 3255  & Symmetric Positive-definite & Yes & 8.0e+06\\
NOS7        & 729   & 4617  & Symmetric Positive-definite & No & 4.1e+09\\
ORSIRR 1    & 1030 & 6858   & Asymmetric & Yes & 1.0e+02\\
SHERMAN4    & 1104 & 3786   & Asymmetric & Yes & 7.2e+03\\ 
ORSIRR 2    & 886  & 5970   & Asymmetric & Yes & 1.7e+05\\
ORSREG 1    & 2205 & 14133  & Asymmetric & Yes & 1.0e+02\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:2-1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If I add your code fragment in standard article` document, it works without any error. To confirm this, please extend your code snippet to complete small document, which we can tast and which reproduce your problem.

Comment: With `Wiley-AuthoringTemplate.sty` available [from here](https://authorservices.wiley.com/author-resources/book-authors/prepare-your-manuscript/wiley-latex-template.html)  the issue seems to be reproducible.

Answer (score 4):

As [Zarko already mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/502016/argument-of-begin-has-an-extra/502024#comment1268009_502016), the code you posted works perfectly fine in a standard documentclass such as `article` or `book`. If you however add the `Wiley-AuthoringTemplate` package you recieve the error message you described.

Looking through the Authoring Template Manual, we can find the following example table (See p. 27):

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Enter table caption here.\label{tab1}}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}}
\toprule
Tap &Relative &Relative &Relative mean\\
number &power (dB) &delay (ns) &power (dB)\\
\midrule
3 &0$-9.0$ &68,900\footnotemark[1] &$-12.8$\\
4 &$-10.0$ &12,900\footnotemark[2] &$-10.0$\\
5 &$-15.0$ &17,100 &$-25.2$\\
\botrule
\end{tabular}}{\footnotetext[]{Source: Example for table source text.}
\footnotetext[1]{Example for a first table footnote. Example for a first
table footnote. Example for a first table footnote. Example for a first
table footnote.}
\footnotetext[2]{Example for a second table footnote.}}
\end{table}
```

If we break this down to the minimal example possible and compare this to the standard approach (that you used), we can see the following differences that I marked with `<-----` in the below comparison. In the Wiley approach, the `\caption` command has three instead of only one argument. The first one ist the caption text itself, the second one contains the `tabular` environment and the last one contains the optional table notes.

Standard approach:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{<caption>}
\begin{tabular}{...} 
<contents>
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Wiley approach:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{<caption>}{%<-----
\begin{tabular}{...} 
<contents> 
\end{tabular}}%<----
{<tablenotes>}%<-----
\end{table}
```

Your code is therefore missing the set of `{}` around the `tabular` environment as well as the empty set of `{}` for the non existing table notes.
In the following MWE I have done the above mentioned changes to make your code compilable:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{Wiley-AuthoringTemplate}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[bh!]
\centering
\caption{Properties of benchmark matrices\label{tab:2-1}}{%
\begin{tabular}{cccccc} 
 \hline
 matrix          & rank & nonzero  & type & diagonally& Condition  \\
                   &        & elements &       & dominant & Number     \\ \hline
PLAT1919    & 1919 & 32399  & Symmetric Indefinite & No & 1.0e+02\\ 
PLAT362           & 362   & 5786    & Symmetric Indefinite & No & 7.1e+11\\
GR 30 30    & 900   & 7744  & Symmetric Positive-definite & Weakly & 3.8e+02\\
BCSSTK22    & 138   & 696       & Symmetric Indefinite & No & 1.7e+05\\
NOS4        & 100   & 594       & Symmetric Positive-definite & No & 2.7e+03\\ 
HOR 131     & 434   & 4710  & Asymmetric & No & 1.3e+05\\ 
NOS6        & 675   & 3255  & Symmetric Positive-definite & Yes & 8.0e+06\\
NOS7        & 729   & 4617  & Symmetric Positive-definite & No & 4.1e+09\\
ORSIRR 1    & 1030 & 6858   & Asymmetric & Yes & 1.0e+02\\
SHERMAN4    & 1104 & 3786   & Asymmetric & Yes & 7.2e+03\\ 
ORSIRR 2    & 886  & 5970   & Asymmetric & Yes & 1.7e+05\\
ORSREG 1    & 2205 & 14133  & Asymmetric & Yes & 1.0e+02\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}}{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Side note: If you want to use `\rowcolor`, add the `table` option as follows: `\documentclass[table]{book}`.

Comment: Thank you guys. It works properly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I came across this issue preparing a manuscript from Wiley Jan 2021.